# PhoneGap Support to FlexBox Model

Tags: css, cordova, flexbox

Does PhoneGap browser support CSS flexbox model? What flexbox spec (new or old)?

I tried with -webkit-flex spec but no luck!

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am missing something here, CSS support is specific to the device its being run on.  At this point in time, all Android and iOS are supporting the 2009 Flexbox spec in their native browser, as well as Blackberry 7.  Blackberry 10 is supporting the standard properties.

To be safe going forwards, you'll want both old and new properties:

```
.foo {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

Not sure if PhoneGap can be compiled to work on Windows mobile devices, but if they're supporting flexbox, you're looking for `-ms-flexbox`.

http://caniuse.com/flexbox